# Change CSS for logged in users WordPress | X Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function

I am attempting to change some css to display:none; when the user is logged in. 
It's just a "Sign In / Register" link. ( so when the user is logged on they wont see it)

```
<span class="hide-this-class-when-logged-in"><a href="#">Sign Up / Register</a></span>
```

I have copied my _header.php file into my child theme, and replaced

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

with this

```
<body<?php echo (is_user_logged_in() ? ' class="logged-in"' : ''); ?>>
```

thinking that this would provide an additional .class for logged in users, so I could then

```
.class {display:block}
.class .logged-in {display:none}
```

but the body got all screwed up,( everything got a float left; ) and I am back to the drawing board.

Any input on this topic, or how to use body_class() with x theme would be really appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Your body thing was good just write your css selectors as `.logged-in .[selector]`

Comment: The theme had it right already, just leave it the way it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your header.php file.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This built in function already tracks user status, as well as a number of other useful states like page template, page id, etc.

Example of output:

```
<body class="home page page-id-403 page-template page-template-page-home logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support custom-background group-blog">
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

```
<body
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    body_class('logged-in');
} else {
    body_class('logged-out');
}
?>
>
```

goes in your _header.php file

```
.logged-in{whatever;}
.logged-out{whatever;}
```

Comment: You should not need to add the `logged-in` class manually. It is part of the default behavior of `body_class()`, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
//create two variables 
    $user_loggedin_class = "loggedin";
    $user_notlogin_class = "notloggin"; 
    // add css like this
    <style type="text/css" >
        .loggedin{
             display: none;
        }
        .notloggin{
             display: display:block;
        }
    </style>
    // your span tag should like this 
    <span class="<?php echo ( (is_user_logged_in())?$user_loggedin_class:$user_notlogin_class );  ?>"><a href="#">Sign Up / Register</a></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, @user can I create variables anywhere in wordpress? or does that need to be in the header.php file?

Comment: Correct, but unnecessary. See my post below.