# Hide and Show items when user logged in and logged out

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have the following code when the user is logged out:

```
<div class="fusion-secondary-main-menu">
       <div class="fusion-row">
            <?php avada_main_menu(); ?>
            <?php avada_mobile_menu_search(); ?>
       <ul id="odp-main-menu-right" class="odp-pl-0">
            <li class="#">
                 <a href=""><i class="far fa-bell odp-mr-1">
                 </i>0</a>
            </li>
            <li id="upload-ad" class="not-logged-in">
                <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(trailingslashit(home_url($wp->request)));?>"
                style="color: #fff;">
                NEW ADVERT
                </a>
            </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

However when the user is logged out it must hide the following and when logged in show the following on the front-end:

```
<li class="#">
    <a href=""><i class="far fa-bell odp-mr-1">
    </i>0</a>
</li>
```

I've used a CSS class to add `display:none` on a class not-logged-in but when logged in, but it is still gone.

When logged in, the wp_login_url must also be replaced by a clickable ID element

Comment: Is it wordpress ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Working on the child theme for dev.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change CSS for logged in users WordPress | X Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280643/change-css-for-logged-in-users-wordpress-x-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
    //Your HTML here needs to be shown when the user is logged in.
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely use it. Can I use an else then for if the user logged in = false?

Comment: Where can I read more on this perhaps?

Comment: Yes you can but  if you need to add html only for not loggedin user, then its better to use !is_user_logged_in() in place of is_user_logged_in()

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! Will definitely work after this

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it works for you.